# How to extract Google Alerts using Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, google-alerts

I need to extract news article headlines from Google alerts using Python 3.7, I tried to use "galerts" library, but I couldn't install it because it doesn't have a newer release which is supported by Python 3.7. Is there any alternative way with which I can scrape the headlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `README` of the galerts library, there is a link to a [google-alerts library](https://github.com/9b/google-alerts) - this supports Python 3.